# Model binding addonLeft.text angular formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap, angular-formly

I am using [bootstrap templates](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap) with [angular-formly](http://angular-formly.com/) and I wanted to bind `addonsLeft.text` to a model so that it dynamically changes once a select option has changed.

This is how an input looks like:

```
  {
    key: 'my_input',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Text',
      addonLeft: {
            text: vm.model.select
      }
    }
  }
```

From what I understood bootstrap templates do not create a model for text / class option and therefore changing the model wouldn't affect the `addonLeft.text`.

Find a non-working example in this jsbin [link](http://jsbin.com/niroyageme/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

I have found a hacky way of doing this butI am not sure if this is the right way.

Here is the solution in this jsbin [link](http://jsbin.com/tabefegajo/edit?js,output).

---

Should I create a custom template instead so that it has a proper model etc? Reason I haven't done this already it's because there is already an implemented solution that would keep my code cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case for **[Formly Expressions](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formly-expressions)**:

```
{
    key: 'my_input',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
        label: 'Text',
        addonLeft: {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    expressionProperties: {
      'templateOptions.addonLeft.text': 'model.select' // <- HERE
    }
}
```

Example JSBin: http://jsbin.com/tudivi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: That's one thing I haven't tried even though I used expressionProperties a lot!! Thanks, works like a charm.